# SonarScanner running inside the docker container cannot access source code

Tags: docker, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, docker-container, sonarscanner

I'm trying to scan the source code of some project with SonarQube and SonarScanner running locally on Docker, OS: Windows.

By providing the next command in the terminal I'm trying to run container with SonarScanner which should scan the code in my current directory (SonarQube instance is running in the background):

```
docker run \
    --rm \
    --network=host \
    -e SONAR_HOST_URL="http://127.0.0.1:9000/" \
    -e SONAR_LOGIN="...some token..." \
    -v $PWD:/usr/src sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli \
    -Dsonar.projectKey=some-project-name
```

After that I get 'EXECUTION SUCCESS' message, but SonarQube shows "No code files were found for analysis" in the "Code" tab (statistics are empty too).

I have tried to add `-Dsonar.sources=some_subdirectory_which_exists_in_the_current_directory` parameter, which results in 'EXECUTION FAILURE' message with "the folder does not exist in base directory" message. So I think that the container just doesn't have access to project files or for some reason it doesn't copy them.